# How to achieve variable distortion along height on single 2D Sprites

Tags: unity-game-engine, shader, height, distortion, urp

I'm trying to achieve an effect on single 2D sprites that is similar to those used on animes when characters are moving fast.

My start point was using the Tilling and Offset node on URP shader graphs to distort the sprite, i could change the tilling based on variables such as time but that didn't achieve the desired effect, the main problem with that node is that it distorts the whole sprite on the same amount, while the desired effect would be a distortion that varies along the height of the sprite.

Anyone got any insights on this?

Here's my reference point,

base sprite:

[image]

distorted (i would like a more detailed - less distorted effect but i hope you get the idea):

[image]

Edit 1: My current progress[image]

Comment: The distortion in the example doesn't illustrate your question because it is likely a new illustration that is swapped out for the character in the first image. Distortion here only seems to vary with the height because the character is wider in the lower body in that pose. You should add a screenshot of your current progress instead of the animation stills. (from an artistic perspective, if the sprite is small, I would recommend drawing the distortion by hand for a few frames.)

Comment: after watching a lot of those animations frame by frame i concluded that it is indeed a distortion (not just a new illustration), as i said my current progress only amounts to distorting the whole sprite by the same amount - which results in just a stretched sprite